# Wix installer in visual studio

Tags: wix

I'm currently working in tridion along with dotnet(visual studio) for template development.
I need to work in WIX installer(I'm new too this part).
can anyone let me know about WIX.How it is used in Visual studio?
Suggest me some articles or url.It will be helpful to me.I have only a short time.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial
This is the best tutorial i found so far...

Just download the toolset via Visual Studio Updates and Extensions